# Вертикальное растягивание блока

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Внутри блока `container` есть три блока: `left`, `main`, `right`. Блоки имеют фиксированую ширину, но их высота зависит от наполнения блока `main`, тоесть от его высоты. Сами блоки `left` и `right` — пустые, от чего и появилась проблема.

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="left"></div>
   <div id="main">text</div>
   <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Стили:

```
<style>
 #container{width:200px}
 #left{float:left;width:50px;height:100%}
 #right{float:right;width:50px;height:100%}
 #main{margin:0 50px}
</style>
```

С такими стилями блоки `left` и `right` просто невидимые. Если же этим блокам установить `min-height`, они не приобретают высоты большей, чем эта минимальная высота, тоесть блоки остаются фиксированой высоты:

[image]

Как можно избавится этой проблемы и сделать "зависимость" высоты боковых блоков от высоты среднего блока?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут нужно работать с position:
абсолютные - по бокам, любое - для контейнера (но обязательно обозначить)

```
<style>

 #container{width:220px;position: relative}

 #left{position:absolute;width:50px;height:100%;background:blue}

 #right{position:absolute; right:0px;width:50px;height:100%;background:gray}

 #main{margin:0 50px;background:red}

</style>

<div id="container"> 
  <div id="left"></div>

  <div id="right"></div>

  <div id="main">много-много текста, и ещё больше 
    <br />

   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось удобно и кроссбраузерно